# Delete again a file via a previous commit that deleted that file in the first place

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

Scenario:

- delete *file.txt* file, commitA and push
- restore *file.txt* via **git checkout commitA~1 file.txt** , commitB and push

I want to delete the file *again* by invoking *commitA* by running the following checkout command:

```
git checkout commitA --file.txt
```

but I get

```
error: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Is there a way to re-delete the file? I could just delete the file add it and commit but I am wondering if I can keep the history clean by reusing an *older commit*?!

Edit: I removed the Source from the file path to avoid confusions

Comment: Minor: the syntax is `git checkout commitA -- file.txt`, that is, the `--` is an argument on its own that simply separates the pathspec from the rest of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to [use `git checkout` to] delete the file *again* by invoking [the commit in which I deleted it] ...

You cannot do that.  This form of `git checkout` (or `git restore` for that matter) can only *add or replace* the file, not *remove* it.

If you know that the file was removed in some specific commit and would like to remove it again, use `git rm` (or `git rm --cached` if the idea includes avoiding modifying the working tree).

If you don't know whether the file existed or not, and simply want to put it back into the same state—that is, restore it to the way it was *if it existed*, or remove it entirely *if it did not exist*, you will need an `if/then` test:  "Did file *F* exist in commit *C?* If yes, use `git checkout` / `git restore`; if no, use `git rm`".  To test whether it existed, consider using `git ls-tree` (useful if you want to check many paths) or `git rev-parse` (useful if you want to check a single path).  You could even use the error from `git checkout` as an indicator that the file did not exist, although that seems a bit clumsy and perhaps error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

because your command is wrong
it should go like this `git restore --Source HEAD~1 file.txt` note that your HEAD will be detached

and if what you want to correct is on-stage use this `git restore --staged file.txt` to unstage it.

Comment: Nope, please pay attention to what I am trying to achieve: I am trying to "play back" the delete file.txt action. I am looking if there is a command were the commit-number and file-name are the input. The commit being that one where the input file was deleted (and later  restored). The command shall delete the file again.

Comment: what you are looking for is  `git reflog` it keep track of everything including what you have deleted. to access them run `git reflog show HEAD` or if you want to filter what out to most recent activities `git reflog show HEAD@{5}`

Comment: You can then checkout to the commitHash of the file you have deleted. I hope this help

Comment: "You can then checkout to the commitHash of the file you have deleted" - I don't want the entire commit but filter to action that the commit had on one file: to delete it.